# Calculate separate percentage value for multiple ID's in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with few columns CitrixID, Wave, DocNumber, Incorrect, correct and Percentage

[image]

How to get separate percentage values for multiple CitrixID's?

I have written the below query in sql but it returns wrong percentage value.

```
 SELECT Citrix_ID, Wave,Document_Number, SUM(Attempt) as Incorrect,SUM(AttemptGreen) as Correct, 
         CONCAT((SUM(AttemptGreen) *100 / (SELECT SUM(AttemptGreen) + SUM(Attempt) FROM tblTrackQuestErrors WHERE Wave='Wave 86' and Document_Number='0123123123116')),'%')  AS Percentage  
         FROM tblTrackQuestErrors WHERE Wave='Wave 86' and Document_Number='0123123123116' group by Citrix_ID,Wave,Document_Number
```

I need the output to be like below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sudhakar, could you please refer to following SELECT and percentage calculation

```
select
    convert(
        decimal(5,2), 
        isnull(correct,0) * 100.0 / case when (isnull(correct,0) + isnull(incorrect,0)) = 0 
                                        then null 
                                        else (isnull(correct,0) + isnull(incorrect,0)) 
                                    end
    ) as [percentage]
from tbl
```

Comment: Awsome Eralper. Its worked like a charm. Thanks for saving time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your tables, but this should work

```
SELECT Citrix_ID, Wave,Document_Number, SUM(Attempt) as Incorrect, SUM(AttemptGreen) as Correct
, SUM(AttemptGreen) *100 / SUM(AttemptGreen) + SUM(Attempt) AS Percentage
,MIN((
  SELECT SUM(T1.AttemptGreen) *100 / SUM(T1.AttemptGreen) + SUM(T1.Attempt) 
  FROM   tblTrackQuestErrors T1
  WHERE  T1.Wave            = tblTrackQuestErrors.Wave
  AND    T1.Document_Number = tblTrackQuestErrors.Document_Number
)) AS Percentage_Multi_CitrixID
FROM   tblTrackQuestErrors
group by Citrix_ID,Wave,Document_Number
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Citrix_ID, Wave,Document_Number, SUM(Attempt) as Incorrect,SUM(AttemptGreen) as Correct, 
        CONCAT(CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2), SUM(AttemptGreen) * 100.0 / CASE WHEN (SUM(AttemptGreen) + SUM(Attempt)) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE (SUM(AttemptGreen) + SUM(Attempt)) END ),'%') as [percentage]
        FROM tblTrackQuestErrors WHERE Wave=@Wave and Document_Number=@Document_Number group by Citrix_ID,Wave,Document_Number